# Get all data from subdocument via graphql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

**Model**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const CustomerGeneralInformation = require('./CustomerGeneralInformation').schema;
const CustomerContact = require('./CustomerContact').schema;
const CustomerFinance=require('./CustomerFinancial').schema;
const CustomerPersonalData=require('./CustomerPersonalData').schema;
const CustomerIdentification=require('./CustomerIdentification').schema;


const Schema=mongoose.Schema;


const CustomerSchema=new Schema({
  

   generalInformation: [CustomerGeneralInformation],
    
    contactData: [CustomerContact],
    financialData:[CustomerFinance],
    personalData:[CustomerPersonalData],
    identificationData:[CustomerIdentification]
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Customer',CustomerSchema);
```

**Graphql Schema**

```
const RootQuery=new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:'RootQueryType',
    fields:{
        customers:{
            type: new GraphQLList(CustomerType),
            resolve(parent,args){
             
            return customer.find({});
            
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**GraphiQl**

```
{
  customers
  {
    id
   generalInformation{
    purposeOfBusiness
  }
  contactData{
    phone
    email
    countryResidence
    mailbox
    houseNo
    zip
    city
  }
    financialData{
      taxNo
      countryTaxation
      refBankIban
      StringrefBankBic
      refBankIban
    }
   
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
{
  "data": {
    "customers": [
      {
        "id": "5fa0f8ea4e028a2cf8d24c3f",
        "generalInformation": {
          "purposeOfBusiness": null
        },
        "contactData": {
          "phone": null,
          "email": null,
          "countryResidence": null,
          "mailbox": null,
          "houseNo": null,
          "zip": null,
          "city": null
        },
        "financialData": {
          "taxNo": null,
          "countryTaxation": null,
          "refBankIban": null,
          "StringrefBankBic": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

SO I have created a customer model which have an id(autogenerated by mongodb) and 5 other fields of schema type.
I have used graphql for creating apis.

Everything is working fine, I have created mutations to add data, its all tested in mongo that data is being saved.

But if you check my graphql output I am **unable to query subdocuments**, it shows null. I want list of all subdocuments with data.

PlEASE HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried this way and its working perfectly,

Firstly as you are passing the whole model in your new Customer model so instead of that I just have stored the ID as a reference.

```
    const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    generalInformation: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "GeneralInfo"
    },
    contactData: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ContactData" },
    financialData: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "FinacialData"
    },
    personalData: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "PersonalData" }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

After that, for CustomerType, I had done this

```
const CustomerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Customer",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    customerContact: {
      type: CustomerContactType,
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return CustomerContact.findById(parent.contactData);
      }
    },
    generalInformation: {
      type: CustomerGeneralType,
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return CustomerGeneral.findById(parent.generalInformation);
      }
    },
    financialData: {
      type: CustomerFinanceType,
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return CustomerFinance.findById(parent.financialData);
      }
    },
    personalData: {
      type: CustomerPersonalType,
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return CustomerPersonal.findById(parent.personalData);
      }
    }
  })
});
```

And them for RootQuery

```
customers: {
      type: new GraphQLList(CustomerType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Customar.find({});
      }
    }
```

and here is my Query:

```
{
  customers{
    id
    generalInformation{
      purposeOfBusiness
    }
    customerContact{
      phone
      email
      countryResidence
    }
    financialData{
      taxNo
    }
  }
}
```

And Output

```
{
  "data": {
    "customers": [
      {
        "id": "5fa3fe066f0fda0568e56456",
        "generalInformation": {
          "purposeOfBusiness": "Test Purpose"
        },
        "customerContact": {
          "phone": "123456798",
          "email": "test@demo.com",
          "countryResidence": "Pak"
        },
        "financialData": {
          "taxNo": "120033244"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```